# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B - Windows IOT - UWP C++ - Servo control?

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot, c++, servo

So currently, I have already developed a uwp application in Visual C++. I ordered a raspberry pi 3 model b from Amazon and its expected to arrive on Wednesday. In my program, I have a button, when I click that button, I need to move a servo 90 degrees. I have the servo kit for raspberry pi here: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01J40NPVW/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J40NPVW). I've looked up documentation on how to do this with UWP but they are all in C# and seem fairly complicated. Anyone have any resources that I could follow that is specifically for C++ UWP? Thanks.

Comment: I do not see how that kit would work with Windows IoT.  It seems to rely on servoblaster which is Linux C code to exploit special features of the Raspberry Pi.  As far as I am aware there is no Windows equivalent.

Comment: If I were to use the same servos, just not the board that it comes with, would I still be able to achieve my task? Isn't the only thing that the GPIO pins are doing is sending out pulses to the motors? I have a video here that seems similar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIROjErwn4A

Comment: The youtube video is using a piece of hardware (PCA9685A) to drive the servo signals.  The kit you bought seems to be using software to drive the servo signals (but the software is doing this in a highly specialised way which has not been ported to Windows).

Comment: Ok, for my current situation, how would you recommend proceeding with this project? I still have the same servos.

Comment: I would check with Monk Makes to see if their kit would work with Windows.  If it won't I'd go for a PCA9685 based solution, but I would use one which had software examples available for Windows IoT.

Comment: I have been looking at this post and it seems like it has the same thing I'm trying to do: http://mscodingblog.blogspot.com/2018/01/control-multiple-servos-using-raspberry.html. In the schematics, what is an i2c connection?

Comment: I2C is a form of serial link.  The Pi hardware supports a variety of serial links - serial link, I2C, and SPI.  The I2C bus uses GPIO 2 and 3 on the Pi (pins 3 and 5).

Comment: Okay so my original plan fell through and I got myself a PCA9685 and wired it up to my raspberry pi. You mentioned something about windows iot based examples. Could you link some?